# How to get list of hub sites and associated sites using Graph Api

Tags: sharepoint-online, hub-site, graph-api

I was able to get the list of hub sites in my tenant using HubSites API and associated sites using search.

I am trying to achieve same scenario using Graph API.

Can someone please help me if there are options.

Thanks,
Venkat Konjeti